# The application cannot make a connection with MDF file even building the project successfully [Visual Studio 2010 C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I just learned Visual Studio 2010 C# for 3 months. I added the data source call "PUBS.MDF" which is the sample database from Microsoft like "NORTHWIND.MDF". and write the code to connect the data source with the following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                        AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PUBS.mdf;
                        Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM authors";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        textBox1.Text = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }

  }
}
```

This code is debugged successfully as the picture below :
[image]

However, after I build the project, install in my computer (window7), and click to open the application (I also click "Run as administrator"), it show the error window as the picture below :
[image]

Someone please help me.

PS.

This is how I add the PUBS.MDF file in my application

1. Click tab "Data"
2. Click "Add New Data Souce..."
3. Select "Database"
4. Select "Dataset"
5. Browse "PUBS.MDF" file

This is how I build the project

1. Click tab "File" > Add > New Project > Visual Studio Installer > Setup Project
2. Right click "Application Folder" > "Add" > "Project Output" > "Primary Output"
3. Right click "Application Folder" > "Add" > "File..." > browse "PUBS.MDF" file
4. At "Solution Explorer" window, right click the project's name > click "Build" and wait until it shows message "Build secceed"

I also upload the project, please download by this link --> http://www.4shared.com/zip/-HLqC-b_/WindowsFormsApplication18.html?

I used to post the question almost the same with this --> [Building project succeed with Access database, can search the data but cannot delete the record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065885/visual-studio-c-building-project-succeed-with-access-database-can-search-the) but in that case, the database was .accdb file and it can be solved by clicking "Run as an administrator" but this case was .MDF file and I don't know why just different type of database file but cannot solve by the same method.

Answer (score 1):

change your connection string as below. it may work:

```
      string constr =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\PUBS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Comment: Sorry, I try as your suggest but it doesn't work, still error.